# Center img responsive in fullscreen container

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design, fullscreen

Im trying to create a fullscreen scrolling page, where you scroll from one container to another.
The container divs (class="block") have a content div (class="blockcontent") with images and text as a content.

My goal is too vertically and horizontally center the content inside the fullscreen divs.

My Problems: the images are scaled bigger then there parent div, or the image link is scaled bigger then the image itself. Also i cant get it vertically centered...

HTML

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="blockcontent">
        <div class="imgcontainer">
            <a href="#"><img src="" alt=""></a>
            <p>description</p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="blockcontent">
        <div class="imgcontainer">
        <a href="#"><img src="" alt=""></a>
        <p>description</p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.block {
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.blockcontent {
    max-width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}
.imgcontainer {
    height: 80%;
}
.imgcontainer img  {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this guide on [how to center with CSS](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-center-anything-with-css-align-a-div-text-and-more/)

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you're just looking for something like this? View as Full Screen since you're using the `vh` `vw` sizing.

```css
section {
  display: block;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

figure {
  margin: 0;
}

section:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: green;
}

section:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: blue;
}

section:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <figure>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">
  </figure>
</section>
<section>
  <figure>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">
  </figure>
</section>
<section>
  <figure>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">
  </figure>
</section>
```